# pem/cer certificate drop to ios simulator: The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

In MacOS versions predating Steve Job's liver failure
certificate drop to iOS simulator used to work.
Not anymore.

[image]

Xcode 11.5 in case it matters.
Drops to the device also result in safari->settings
sequence not opening (but this happens without an
utterance on the iOS part, UNIX legacy you know: except that
mute behaviour implies success rather than failure)

So, any chance I can get this to work to get
connected to an internal https site running trash certificate I have to do this whole dance for?

This is true no matter if I try a pem or cer.
No way Jose. It just does not happen.